# ssh tunnel putty - UI app login not working from browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, putty, ssh-tunnel

I had setup SSH tunnel using putty in my local Windows to remote linux server. I am able to open localhost:8080 in my Windows Chrome browser and I verified SSH tunnel is working as it rendering my UI from the remote machine.

Now, when I enter details to login, its not working. May be I should set some cross domain network calls settings in my remote server application code? I am using React front end app.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. my UI is calling another port (apache karaf) for REST calls. So I added SSH tunnel for the other port also and now my network calls are working.